# ArrayList initialized/accessed using Singleton class

Tags: java, android, arraylist, singleton

I am using an ArrayList in my application.

I would like to know the exact procedure to initialize my ArrayList from a Singleton class.
The data will be used in some other Activities.

Can anybody help to know about Singleton class?

Comment: Please, add some code and further explanation to help us understand the problem.

Comment: What efforts you have done

Comment: I hope you were able to turn in your homework on time!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how to create your singleton class :

```
    public class YourSingleton  {  

        private static YourSingleton mInstance;
        private ArrayList<String> list = null;

        public static YourSingleton getInstance() {
            if(mInstance == null)
                mInstance = new YourSingleton();

            return mInstance;
        }

        private YourSingleton() {
          list = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        // retrieve array from anywhere
        public ArrayList<String> getArray() {
         return this.list;
        }
        //Add element to array
        public void addToArray(String value) {
         list.add(value);
        }
}
```

Anywhere you need to call your arrayList just do :

```
YourSingleton.getInstance().getArray();
```

To add elements to array use :

```
 YourSingleton.getInstance().addToArray("first value");
```

or

```
YourSingleton.getInstance().getArray().add("any value");
```

Comment: Thanks @Anto.. and one more thing is can I use multiple arraylist in same singleton class

Comment: yes you can, and create differents methods to call correct array. In this exemple you have getArray(). You could create getFirstArray(), getSecondArray() etc... Just add your others array in class declaration and initialize them in constructor just like i did for 'list'

Comment: Got an Idea.. Very kind of you@Anto  Lemme checkout and let u know

Comment: How to set data in **list** from singleton class

Comment: edited my post, you need to create a method that will affect the array

Comment: Return statement missing know

Comment: need a big help@Anto I have 3 ArrayLists, which are Name, Age, Location

Comment: in those arraylist i would like to filter by all the three in searchview.. I mean if i wanna search using name or age or location.. how to filter this

Comment: Then that is another question ;) create a new post with sample of your search code !

Comment: Sorry @Anto. What I need is Have to filter any one of the arraylist should filter all the three Values

Comment: I cant add new question here:-(

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the following wikipedia-artikle:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

But keep in mind that singletons are 'global state' and make your sourcecode harder to test. There are lot of people saying: "singletons are evil'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this.

```
public class SingletonClass {

    private static ArrayList<String> strArray;
    private static SingletonClass singleton;

    private SingletonClass(){}

    public static synchronized SingletonClass getConnectionInstance(ArrayList<String> strArray){        
        if (singleton == null) {
             singleton = new SingletonClass();
        }
        this.strArray = strArray;
        return singleton;
    }
}
```